# Symmetry Group of a Degenerate Bilinear Form

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

I was studying a finite dimensional toy model in quantum field theory. Now I need some help from mathematicians.

I am interested in this degenerate bilinear form

$$S(x^{1},x^{2},\cdots,x^{n})\equiv\begin{pmatrix}
x^{1} & x^{2} & \cdots & x^{n}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
\vdots & \vdots  & & \vdots \\
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x^{1} \\
x^{2} \\
\vdots \\
x^{n}
\end{pmatrix}=(x^{1}+x^{2}+\cdots+x^{n})^{2}$$

Obviously, the square matrix of $S$ has zero eigenvectors. For convenience, I denote the above bilinear form in a compact form:

$$S(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}^{T}\cdot\mathbf{S}\cdot\mathbf{x},$$

where $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then, if $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a zero eigenvector of $\mathbf{S}$, one also has

$$S(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{v})=S(\mathbf{x}).$$

The matrix $\mathbf{S}$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_{1}=n$, $\lambda_{2}=0$, $\cdots$, $\lambda_{n-1}=0$, $\lambda_{n}=0$, and eigenvectors

\begin{align}
v_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
\vdots \\
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix},\quad v_{2}&=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix},\quad v_{3}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix},\quad\cdots \\
v_{n-1}&=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix},\quad v_{n}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

Therefore, the matrix $\mathbf{S}$ can be diagonalized via the transformation

$$\mathbf{S}=\mathbf{G}\cdot\mathbf{D}\cdot\mathbf{G}^{-1},$$

where

$$\mathbf{D}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & n  
\end{pmatrix},\quad\mathrm{and}\quad\mathbf{G}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 & -1 & \cdots & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Suppose $\mathbf{v}$ is linked with $\mathbf{x}$ via some linear transformation $\mathbf{g}\in\mathrm{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{g}\cdot\mathbf{x}$, do the collection of all such $\mathbf{g}$ form an algebra? If it does, what is this algebra?

My motivation of this question is the following:

The transformation $\mathbf{x}\rightarrow\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{v}$ is a finite dimensional analog of infinitesimal gauge transformations in quantum field theory, and the matrix $\mathbf{g}$ is an analog of the Lie algebra of the gauge group.

Comment: So you're asking about the set of all $\mathbf g$ such that there is *any* $\mathbb x$ such that $S(\mathbf g\mathbf x) = 0$?

Comment: The "such" in "all such $\mathbf g$" is unclear.